# How to change my code for making layout like a pictures in css

Tags: css, css-float

**HTML**

```
    <div id="header"><h1>Scott's Favorite Things</h1>
        <div id="header2"><h2>Cars, Sports, and Music</h2></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#header{
    border:5px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;

}

h1{
    float:right;
    clear: both;
}
div#header2 h2{
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
div#header2{
    border:5px;
    border-color: orange;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 5px;

}
```

Here I post the link to the things I have and i want to:

[**Current result of mine**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPkSx.png)

[**Result that I wanna make**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySynw.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `text-align: right` instead of `float: right` and remove the default `margin` from `h1` and `h2`.

Look at this snippet:

```css
div#header {
  border: 5px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}

div#header h1 { /* Added header to h1 because I dont want to style every h1 */
  text-align: right; /* Changed from float to text-align */
  clear: both;
  margin: 0; /* remove the default margin */
}

div#header2 h2 {
  text-align: right; /* Changed from float to text-align */
  clear: both;
  margin: 0; /* remove the default margin */
}

div#header2 {
  border: 5px;
  border-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Scott's Favorite Things</h1>
  <div id="header2">
    <h2>Cars, Sports, and Music</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a nested HTML-structure an style each div via CSS.

The HTML:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="head-wrapper">
    Lorem Ipsum
    <div class="small-head-wrapper">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    Your Main Content
  </div>
</div>
```

The the CSS:

```
.main-wrapper {
  border: solid 5px green;
}

.main-wrapper .head-wrapper {
  text-align: right;
  border: solid 5px red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.main-wrapper .head-wrapper .small-head-wrapper {
  border: solid 5px orange;
}

.main-wrapper .content-wrapper {
  border: solid 5px blue;
}
```

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/zxvvqszx/